# Is it possible to program PIC18F device with .hex and .bin files

Tags: pic, mplab, pickit

I have .bin and .hex files that I want to load into my PIC18F2480 device. I also have a .doc file explaining how to configure PIC18F2480 before programming. I've been told that it is possible to use PICkit 2(3) programmer and these 3 files to program a brand new PIC18F2480 device.

[Here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/15j9m8) you can find the files.

I could not make it with PICkit 3 programmer and MPLAB X IDE/IPE because I don't know how to combine all the files (.hex + .bin + some settings).

Would you, professional PIC users, take a quick and experienced look on the files and let me know if this is really possible?

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way is to use the IPE.

File->Import->Hex

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know that it is possible to import .hex file. But what about .bin file and the settings I have!? Should I load a .bin file somewhere?

Comment: Just use the hex file and ignore the .bin if you are using IPE.

Comment: I did so but there was no success! :-(

Comment: Let me ask you one more question...

Comment: ... I have two .bin files (for eeprom and flash). You can find them here: https://www.sendspace.com/file/0nud7o  How can I use them with PICkit 3 programmer and MPLAB IDE/IPE? Should I convert them to a .hex file before programming?